# puppeteer says Exception: Websocket url not found

Tags: dart, puppeteer

For the first time, I am using puppeteer with dart , here the simple code :

```
import 'package:puppeteer/puppeteer.dart';

main() async {
  var browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  await browser.close();
}
```

In pubspec yaml file:

```
dependencies:
  puppeteer: ^1.16.1
  websocket: ^0.0.5
#  path: ^1.6.0
```

when I am trying to run this piece of code with dart command:

```
dart puppy1_test.dart
```

I am getting this exception :

```
Unhandled exception:
Exception: Websocket url not found
#0      _waitForWebSocketUrl (package:puppeteer/src/puppeteer.dart:311:3)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      Puppeteer.launch (package:puppeteer/src/puppeteer.dart:170:30)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      main (file:///D:/project/<removed>/dl/puppy1/test/puppy1_test.dart:7:33)
#3      _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:307:19)
#4      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:174:12)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by deleting the `.local-chromium` folder. In this folder the chrome application is stored.

I suspect that the reason was a version mismatch, because I updated the dart version, after the creation of the project.